# Numerical stability for Euler method - difference between $h<\frac{2}{|\lambda|}$ and $h<\frac{2\cdot |Re(\lambda_k)|}{|\lambda|^2}$?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

When looking at the numerical stability of a system of differential equations - what is the difference between these two equations that give the minimum step size for stability? How do you know which equation to use? Is it to do with whether your eigenvalues have an imaginary component? $h<\dfrac{2}{|\lambda|}$ and $h<\dfrac{2\cdot |Re(\lambda_k)|}{|\lambda|^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual condition is $$|1+hλ|<1\iff 2hRe(λ)+h^2|λ|^2<0$$ for eigenvalues $λ$ with negative real part. This leads to the second formula $$h<\frac{-2·Re(λ)}{|λ|^2}.$$

The first of your conditions is only valid for real $λ$ or as a guideline when only the Lipschitz constant as upper bound for the eigenvalues is accessible.

---

For any practical work, do not use the Euler methods.

Comment: so let's say I had the eigenvalues $-2+i\sqrt{3}$ and $-2+i\sqrt{3}$, I would just plug them into the equation you've given to find the step size required?

Comment: Yes. But remember that $h<\frac47$ only guarantees that the trajectory of the Euler method eventually converges to 0. Which can be much slower than the $e^{-2t}$ reduction in amplitude of the exact solution.